# как забрать файл с html страницы с помощью исполнения ссылки в браузере

Tags: php, html, html5, tag

Подскажите пожалуйста, как забрать файл с БИК-ами : [со страницы ЦБ](http://www.cbr.ru/PSystem/payment_system/?UniDbQuery.Posted=True&UniDbQuery.To=08.12.2020#BikFormData)

не кликая на ссылку для скачивания на этой странице (Справочник БИК на 08.12.2020).

Подробнее: необходимо выгружать бики на определенную дату. Дата зашита в общей ссылке на страницу. В ссылке на прямое скачивание справочника БИК -только id, который никак не вычислишь. Поэтому идея привязать к адресу html-страницы относительную ссылку на тэг с ссылкой для скачивания файла и исполнить её в браузере.

Спасибо.

Comment: PHP не владею, но задача решается относительно просто: скачиваем страницу с нужной датой, в ней ищем ссылку на файл, например по XPath `/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div[8]/p/a/@href` и получаем относительную ссылку на файл.

Comment: viilpe, спасибо. Попробовал добавить к ссылке основной xpath: 'http://www.cbr.ru/PSystem/payment_system/?UniDbQuery.Posted=True&UniDbQuery.To=08.12.2020#BikFormData/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div[8]/p/a/@href'. Не скачивается. Может, неправильно соединил?

Comment: нет это так просто не делается. Вам сначала нужно скачать страничку, потом в этой страничке выполнить поиск ссылки на файл как таковой (XPath это один из многих способов сделать это), а затем уже сделать ссылку на файл. Это принцип (который я протестировал на вашей ссылке), он не зависит от конкретного языка программирования.

Comment: villpe, а если относительная ссылка всегда одинаковая, можно ли сгенерить такую общую ссылку на скачивание, чтобы в ней менять только дату? Напр., ссылка_на_общую_страницу_дата_25_01_2015_относит_ссылка_на_файл,

Comment: Вы же сами написали, что ID угадать нельзя.

Comment: Хотелось задать команду через браузер: ищи на странице такой-то содержимое тэга, который можешь найти по ссылке. Предполагал, что @href - это и есть переменная, которая заменяет id.